# Why is registerForContextMenu passing onCreateContextMenu a null ContextMenuInfo?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

In onCreate, I attach a linear layout view to a variable `activeView`. I then call `registerForContextMenu(activeView)`. It appears that everything works properly, the context menu gets created, the items are clickable, however, in `onContextItemSelected`, I call `AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo()` and I get a nullpointerexception. I've traced the null menuInfo variable all the way back to find that `registerForContextMeu(activeView)` is passing OnCreateContextMenu a null ContextMenuInfo from the start. Why is this happening? I do the same process for a different view, a listView, alongside the linearlayout, and the problem doesn't exist there.

Comment: If you have both `OnItemLongClickListener` and `registerForContextMenu` set you have to return `false` in the listener to avoid `AdapterContextMenuInfo` being null. I actually call `registerForContextMenu` in the listener because I'm disabling the context menu for certain list items and it works fine.

Comment: Thx @3k-!! It took me hours to find this solution. Returning `false` in the listener did the job!

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to get out of getMenuInfo()? In any case, I don't think it will be populated by a LinearLayout, I believe at most you'll be able to get the View (the same LinearLayout) which spawned the menu.